# How can I return multiple tuple values as 1 string

Tags: c#, while-loop, tuples

This is what I want: A method that will concatenate all the returned values into one block. At the moment each result is sent as a single string.   [current results of my code that I would like concatinated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCp5g.png)

```
     static async void NotifyEntriesByWorkSpace(Dictionary<string, List<TimeEntry>> EntriesByWorkspace, string strChatURL)
    {
        foreach (var entry in EntriesByWorkspace)
        {
            var timeEntry = entry.Value;
            string prevStoryId = "";
            string strTitle = "";
            var minsLogged = 0;
            foreach (var item in timeEntry)
            {
                Tuple<string, int, string> entryData = GetEntryData(prevStoryId, item);
                prevStoryId = entryData.Item1;
                minsLogged = minsLogged + entryData.Item2;
                strTitle = entryData.Item3;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(strTitle + ": " + minsLogged + " min(s)");
            await SendEntriesByWorkspaceMessage(strChatURL, strTitle, minsLogged);
        }
    }

    static async Task SendEntriesByWorkspaceMessage(string strChatURL, string strTitle, int minsLogged)
    {
        await sendMessage(strChatURL, strTitle + ": " + minsLogged / 60 + " hour(s)" + " " + minsLogged % 60 + " min(s)");
    }

    static Tuple<string, int, string> GetEntryData(string prevStoryId, TimeEntry item)
    {
        var storyId = item.StoryID;
        string prevStoryId_ = "";
        string strTitle = "";
        var minsLogged = 0;
        strTitle = Workspaces.getWorkspaceFromCache(item.WorkspaceID).Title;
        if (prevStoryId != storyId)
        {
            minsLogged = item.TimeInMinutes;
            prevStoryId_ = storyId;
        }
        else
        {
            minsLogged = minsLogged + item.TimeInMinutes;
        }
        return Tuple.Create(prevStoryId_, minsLogged, strTitle);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```cs
     static async void NotifyEntriesByWorkSpace(Dictionary<string, List<TimeEntry>> EntriesByWorkspace, string strChatURL)
    {
        string block = "";
        foreach (var entry in EntriesByWorkspace)
        {
            var timeEntry = entry.Value;
            string prevStoryId = "";
            string strTitle = "";
            var minsLogged = 0;
            foreach (var item in timeEntry)
            {
                Tuple<string, int, string> entryData = GetEntryData(prevStoryId, item);
                prevStoryId = entryData.Item1;
                minsLogged = minsLogged + entryData.Item2;
                strTitle = entryData.Item3;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(strTitle + ": " + minsLogged + " min(s)");
            block += strTitle + ": " + minsLogged / 60 + " hour(s)" + " " + minsLogged % 60 + " min(s)\n";
        }

        await sendMessage(strChartUrl, block);
    }
```

The idea is to instead of `sendMessage()` every entry, collect entries into a `string` then output it once the whole `foreach` loop completed.

The `string` is manually separated by `\n`, but some ideas like make a `entriesList` and then eventually `String.Join("\n", entriesList)` might result in more clear code flow. It depends on your liking.